# Parsing of JSON from Kafka to Elasticsearch

Tags: json, parsing, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I am trying to pass a document of JSON arrays from Kafka to elasticsearch. My JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "A": "---",
  "B": "---",
  "C": "---",
  "D": "---",
  "ABC": "---"
}
```

Due to some reason, Kafka is not able to parse this doc and I am getting an error as:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for ROOT starting at [Source: [B@7563b995; line: 1, column: 0])
at [Source: [B@7563b995; line: 1, column: 3]
at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase._reportMismatchedEndMarker(JsonParserBase.java:487)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:473)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectReader._initForReading(ObjectReader.java:828)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:752)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:473)
at org.elasticsearch.river.kafka.IndexDocumentProducer.addMessagesToBulkProcessor(IndexDocumentProducer.java:71)
at org.elasticsearch.river.kafka.KafkaWorker.consumeMessagesAndAddToBulkProcessor(KafkaWorker.java:107)
at org.elasticsearch.river.kafka.KafkaWorker.run(KafkaWorker.java:78)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It works fine if my data is of the format:

```
{"A": "---", "B": "---", "C": "---", "D": "---", "ABC": "---"}
```

I have several elements that I want to pass as an array in the document. Any idea why I am getting the error for the first format of JSON data? Thanks

Comment: are you doing `bulk import`? what version of `ES` and `kafka-river` you are using?

Comment: I am using ES 1.6. I followed this link : https://github.com/mariamhakobyan/elasticsearch-river-kafka

Comment: ok, but what operation you are performing? bulk import?

Comment: yes, I am trying to pass many elements in a JSON array.

Comment: Trying to pass many elements in json doc is NOT bulk import. It's considered as single doc by ES. I think, you need to provide well formated json doc as required by bulk import. First try to make it work for single json doc.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because your `JSON` is not proper for `bulk import`

From the [Official Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), This is the proper JSON structure

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

> NOTE: the final line of data must end with a newline character \n.

That is why the second format works and first one was throwing error.

Also on a side note [rivers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/index.html) have been **removed** from `ES 2.0`. You might want to look at [kafka plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please tell me how the format should be for a single doc import instead of a bulk import?

Comment: I have not used kafka-river but you can look at [index api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html).  something like this `curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/1' -d '{"A": "---", "B": "---", "C": "---", "D": "---", "ABC": "---"}' ` will do

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same errors when trying to send one message with multiple lines, using ES BulkRequestBuilder API directly (no plugins in between). Solved the issue by making sure the full message is represented as one line (only one new line character at the end of the message).
Also make sure your message is sent as one line to Kafka as well.

You can take a look at the code here: https://github.com/reachkrishnaraj/kafka-elasticsearch-standalone-consumer/tree/branch2.0
it's an open source project a few of us are working on.

I have not used the Kafka plugin that ChintanShah25 suggested - it might also serve your purpose well.